# Webpack dev server generated bundle js file BUT does not render anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I recently ejected from react and tried to configure webpack/babel to my project. So far I'm stuck with running the server and not rendering anything but a blank page.

project structure:

dist

- index_bundle.js

public

- index.html

src

- index.js

webpack.config.js

Here are my files:

**webpack.config.js**

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: 'index_bundle.js',
    },
    devServer: {
        compress: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        open: true,
        overlay: true,
        hot: true,
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
            loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/i,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        },
        {
            test: /\.svg$/,
            loader: 'svg-inline-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|jpe?g|png|gif|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/,
            loader : 'file-loader'
        },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [
        '.ts',
        '.js' // add this
        ]
    },
    plugins: [new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
        template: __dirname + '/public/index.html',
        filename: 'index.html',
        inject: 'body'
    })]
};
```

**index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>

      <Provider store={store}>
        <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>
          <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <App />
          </MuiThemeProvider>    
        </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
      </Provider>


  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>Ad Manager</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the index.html being added to the dist folder during a build?

Comment: @Jason, It should be b/c of the `HtmlWebPackPlugin` so the error seems to be in the code - @Corzo are there any errors in the console?